# Change "From" in outlook VBA Macro

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a macro in outlook that sends out email on its own using my personal email addres.  But I have another email which I have "send as" permission to, and want the macro to use that email address to send out emails. In the macro i have 
objmail.to, objectmail.cc and objmail.bcc but i don't have objmail.from to hardcode the send email address. Is there anyway I can accomplish this.

```
 If ChkResolved = True Then
    If ChkEnglish = True Then
        If ChkLan = True Then
           objMail.To = "xxxx@test.com"
           objMail.Body = "Test" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Signature

         End If
    End If
 End If
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to go for mailitem.SentOnBehalfOfName and put into their as string the Name of the Mailbox as displayed in outlook

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Outlook 2007 or above then the [MailItem.SendUsingAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311%28v=office.15%29.aspx) property provides this functionality.

Comment: I am using outlook 2010. I tried it anyway, but no success.